How to properly propagate an error through non-error function?
Let's say i want to use a function F : (A -> B) -> C which i cannot modify. I, however, want to pass a function g : A -> Result<B, Err> as an argument instead.
I would want a function G : (A -> Result<B, Err>) -> Result<C, Err> that would "propagate" any error resulting from calling g.
Using exceptions, I could do something like
fn transform_to_err(F : (A -> B) -> C, g : A -> Result<B, Err>) -> Result<C, Err> {
    
    fn g_panic (a : A) -> B {
        match g(a) {
            Ok(b) => b
            Err => panic("g_panic error")
        }
    }

    try {
        Ok(F(g_panic)) 
    } catch exception {
        Err
    }
}

Is there a way to do something like this properly handling the results? This way also doesn't allow for algebraic errors which makes it pretty underwhelming.
Here is an example where sum10 acts as F and sqrt_err as g
use std::f64::consts::E;

/// Suppose this function is external and we cannot change it
fn sum10(fun: impl Fn(f64) -> f64) -> f64 {
    let mut sum = 0.;
    for i in 0..10 {
        sum += E.powf(fun(i as f64));
    }
    sum
}

/// We want to use this function with sum10 but it returns a Result
fn sqrt_err(x: f64) -> Result<f64, String> {
    if x < 0.0 {
        Err("Negative value".to_string())
    } else {
        Ok(x.sqrt())
    }
}

What I want is to use sum10 with sqrt_err as the argument, and if at some point sqrt_err is called and returns the Error variant, the error is returned instead.
// So what I want would be equivalent to:
fn sum10_error(fun: impl Fn(f64) -> Result<f64, String>) -> Result<f64, String> {
    let mut sum = 0.;
    for i in 0..10 {
        sum += E.powf(fun(i as f64)?);
    }
    Ok(sum)
}


Can you specify which functions you cannot modify, and which functions you pass as an arguments to which functions? I find your question pretty hard to follow. You are using a pseudo-code to express types of functions. Can you express this using Fn trait? If you could express this concept in some other functional language it could also help with providing Rust's translation.

When you write F: (A -> B) -> C do you mean that for all types A, B, and C, this function takes two arguments, first being function A -> B, and the second one being C, or that F takes only one argument - function from A to B and then returns C? Because second one is impossible to write afaik.

@AleksanderKrauze Ideally, what I would like to do is turn any function like F into one that takes a function that returns Result and propagates any error that the argument function returns. Also, the letters for the types are confusing, so I have posted an example with actual types  to try and make it more clear.

The other answer is incorrect. It is possible to do exactly what is asked. It is just not idiomatic.
playground
use std::f64::consts::E;

fn sum10(fun: impl Fn(f64) -> f64) -> f64 {
    let mut sum = 0.;
    for i in 0..10 {
        sum += E.powf(fun(i as f64));
    }
    sum
}

fn sqrt_err(x: f64) -> Result<f64, String> {
    if x < 0.0 {
        Err("Negative value".to_string())
    } else {
        Ok(x.sqrt())
    }
}

fn transform_to_err<'a, F, G, A, B, C, Error>(f: F, g: G) -> Result<C, Error>
where
    F: FnOnce(Box<dyn Fn(A) -> B + 'a>) -> C + std::panic::UnwindSafe,
    G: Fn(A) -> Result<B, Error> + std::panic::UnwindSafe + 'a,
    Error: Send + std::any::Any,
{
    // Wrap the error to make sure captured panics are sent from this function
    struct ErrorWrapper<E>(E);
    
    // Wrap g such that it panics instead of returning an error
    let g_panic = move |a: A| {
        match g(a) {
            Ok(ret) => ret,
            Err(error) => {
                // prevent running the panic hook
                std::panic::resume_unwind(Box::new(ErrorWrapper(error)));
            }
        }
    };
    // Catch the error
    std::panic::catch_unwind(move ||f(Box::new(g_panic))).map_err(|error|{
        match error.downcast::<ErrorWrapper<Error>>() {
            Ok(error) => error.0,
            Err(error) => std::panic::resume_unwind(error),
        }
    })
}

fn main() {
    let ret = transform_to_err(sum10, sqrt_err);
    println!("{:?}", ret);
}


The catch_unwind docs pretty clearly state: "It is not recommended to use this function for a general try/catch mechanism." Can you do this? Yes. Should you? Absolutely not. A panic is indicative of broken code or some other hard failure state.

Also note that if you compile your code with panic=abort, then it won't work altogether. If this code would be in library, then you have no control which setting final users will choose.

No. What you are asking for is fundamentally not possible. You could go the other way around. If sum10 had signature:
fn sum10<E>(fun: impl Fn(f64) -> Result<f64, E>) -> Result<f64, E> { ... }

Then you could cut out error using ! (never type) or Infallible. However you cannot change control flow of the sum10, when it is already defined.
Note that with your specific example with floating point numbers if all you want to do is check that a number is not positive before calculating its square root, you can rely on fact, that square root of negative number is actually defined to be NaN, and all other calculations using NaN values will "saturate" to NaN. If that is acceptable to you, you can just see if the final value produced by sum10 is NaN or not.
This will not break control flow early (such as ? operator would), but probably it can be acceptable for your problem.
